# Octagon Lifting Plates on a Boat

Tags: weightlifting, deadlifts

I read a thread with most everyone saying octagon plates aren't good for deadlifts. Is this due to poor spinning collars of some barbells that use bushings instead of bearings and lack of adequate competition collars to secure the plates safely? Or people with improper form returning plates to an incorrect position? If I were in a ship on rough seas, would I want round plates...

Answer (score 3):

Octagon plates or any non-round plates are regarded as bad for deadlifts because hey often rotate during the pull. Unless it lands perfectly on a side, it'll role either away from you or towards you. This requires you to do a full reset each time.

This has nothing to do with improper or proper form. It's just something that happens.

> If I were in a ship on rough seas, would I want round plates

I'm not a boat expert, but I'd imagine you wouldn't want anything as dense as a weight plate to freely move about. It would risk significant damage. Octagon plates still rotate pretty easily, especially on a boat in rough waters.